# Laplace vs Fourier density representation of a positive rv

Tags: probability, probability-theory, laplace-transform

Given a general random variable $X$ with density function $f(x)$ and characteristic function $\phi_X(u)$ we can go back and forth between the density and the characteristic by using the Fourier transform relations :
\begin{equation}
\phi_X(u)=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-iux}f(x)dx
\end{equation}and 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-iux}\phi_X(u)du
\end{equation}

However, if X is a non-negative random variable the Laplace is said to be more useful but I don't see exactly why.

First of all, the Laplace transform is defined in terms of a complex variable $s$, meaning that the characteristic function
\begin{equation}
\phi_X(s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx}f(x)dx
\end{equation}

is a function of a complex variable $s$.

Moreover, the inversion  Laplace transform is ugly:
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\lim_{T\to \infty}\int_{\gamma-iT}^{\gamma+iT}e^{sx}\phi_X(s)ds
\end{equation}

To me, using the Fourier  versions
\begin{equation}
\phi_X(u)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-iux}f(x)dx
\end{equation}and 
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-iux}\phi_X(u)du
\end{equation}
 is simpler (but is it correct?).

I know that $\phi_X(s)$ is the extended characteristic function, does this mean that we just  set the real part of $s$ equal to zero in order to obtain the characteristic function? Could someone shade some light on this please.

Comment: "the Laplace [transform] is said to be more useful" Source?

Comment: I've seen it multiple times related to applications of time changes processes ( which take values on the positive line). There the weapon of choice is the Laplace transform (of the density, for a point in time). So, I was wondering why should one prefer that, just because the (extended) characteristic function has a nice formula? @ Did wouldn't you work with Laplace transform if you had to work with subordinators (for example)?